# Nested Links and Buttons not working in Mozilla, IE, and Edge

Tags: html, hyperlink, nested, anchor

as the title states I am having a slight issue with my HTML due to improper nesting (most likely). The issue I am having is that my link that act as anchor anchor aren't working properly, as if they were disabled. This code worked in Chrome, but not in Mozilla, Edge, and Internet Explorer. Is there an easy fix for this or does it require me to completely reformat my HTML structure? I threw in a few extra examples I found on here for reference (still not working).

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/haca/pen/dzgogG?editors=1100

HTML:

```
<div id="backdrop">
  <div id="hero">
    <h1>Haca</h1>
    <h3>Student</h3>
    <div id="options">
      <a href="#abt" alt="link">About Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="abt">About Section</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background: #2e2e2e;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

*{
    transition: .3s;
}

#about{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#hero{
    height: 50%;
    min-height:400px;
    width: 100vw;
    background: url("imgs/space2.gif");
    background-size: 11%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    z-index: -1;
}

#hero h3 img{
    height: 1em;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}

#hero h1{
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: rgb(245, 251, 255);
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1.5vh;
    font-weight: 100;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #d1d1d1,
               0 2px 0 #909090,
               0 3px 0 #626161;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
        -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(3deg);
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}

#hero h3{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: rgb(245, 251, 255);
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 100;
          text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #d1d1d1,
               0 2px 0 #909090,
               0 3px 0 #626161;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
            -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(3deg);
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}

#options{
    margin-top: 5vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 3vh;
    margin-top: 3vh;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
            -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(3deg);
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}

#options button{
    color: rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.92);
    background: rgb(245, 251, 255);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

It does work in chrome, but not in Firefox, Edge, or Internet Explorer. I was wondering how I could get it to work in those browsers? Thanks

Comment: What is need to have button in anchor tag?

Comment: A `button` in  an `a` is an error, so don't do this. If it works in Chrome but not in FF, IE or Edge, that's just because different browsers have different error handling routines.

Comment: Okay, I understand that buttons shouldn't be inside links and I have corrected the code to reflect that. I am still however facing the same issue as per the title when I use pure links to anchor to another section. I don't believe this is a using a button issue; however, I believe its a nesting issue. Thanks.

Comment: What you currently have in your codepen works fine in that regard - when you click on “About Link”, it jumps to the “About Section”. (Since that section is only as high as that text content requires, you of course don’t see _much_ happening here - but the basic thing is working.)

Comment: It does work in chrome, but not in Firefox, Edge, or Internet Explorer. I was wondering how I could get it to work in those browsers?